# Automatic conversion of the advanced string formatter from the old style

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

Is there any automatic way to convert a piece of code from python's old style string formatting (using `%`) to the new style (using `.format`)? For example, consider the [formatting of a PDB atom specification](http://cupnet.net/pdb_format/):

```
spec = "%-6s%5d %4s%1s%3s %1s%4d%1s   %8.3f%8.3f%8.3f%6.2f%6.2f          %2s%2s"
```

I've been converting some of these specifications by hand as needed, but this is both error prone, and time-consuming as I have many such specifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`pyupgrade`](https://github.com/asottile/pyupgrade)

```
pyupgrade --py3-plus <filename>
```

You can convert to f-strings ([formatted string literals](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)) instead of `.format()` with

```
pyupgrade --py36-plus <filename>
```

You can install it with

```
pip install pyupgrade
```

Answer (score 3):

The functionality of the two forms does not match up exactly, so there is no way you could automatically translate every `%` string into an equivalent `{}` string or (especially) vice-versa.

Of course there is a lot of overlap, and many of the sub-parts of the two formatting languages are the same or very similar, so someone *could* write a partial converter (which could, e.g., raise an exception for non-convertible code).

For a small subset of the language like what you seem to be using, you could do it pretty trivially with a simple regex—every pattern starts with `%` and ends with one of `[sdf]`, and something like `{:\1\2}` as a replacement pattern ought to be all you need.

But why bother? Except as an exercise in writing parsers, what would be the benefit? The `%` operator is not deprecated, and using `%` with an existing `%` format string will obviously do at least as well as using `format` with a `%` format string converted to `{}`.

If you *are* looking at this as an exercise in writing parsers, I believe there's an incomplete example buried inside [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com).

---

Some differences that are hard to translate, off the top of my head:

- `*` for dynamic field width or precision; `format` has a similar feature, but does it differently.
- `%(10)s`, because `format` tries to interpret the key name as a number first, then falls back to a dict key.
- `%(a[b])s`, because `format` doesn't quote or otherwise separate the key from the rest of the field, so a variety of characters simply can't be used.
- `%c` takes integers or single-char strings; `:c` only integers.
- `%r`/`%s`/`%a` analogues are not part of the format string, but a separate part of the field (which also comes on the opposite side).
- `%g` and `:g` have slightly different cutoff rules.
- `%a` and `!a` don't do the exact same thing.

The actual differences aren't listed anywhere; you will have to dig them out by a thorough reading of the [Format Specification Mini-Language](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) vs. the [`printf`-style String Formatting language](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting).

Comment: I didn't realize that the (mini) languages did not completely overlap. I thought the old `%`-style was simply a subset of the new-style with the exception of a fill characters of `{}`. Are there more examples?

Comment: @Hooked field justification `<`, `^` and `>` - attribute access and subscript - custom types can support specific formats, eg: `'{0:%H:%M:%S} {1:^60} {0.year} {2[hello]}'.format(dt, 'some field', {'hello': 'goodbye'})`

Comment: @JonClements: Isn't that an example of how the new-style is more powerful than the old style? Looking through the docs, it seems to be the case that every old-style string can be translated into a new-style string, although the reverse is not true.

Comment: @Patrick Indeed, but I hope it also demonstrates that in fact, old style string converted to new style strings, that are already new style strings, might result in incorrect new style strings...

Comment: @JonClements: I don't think that's the question that the OP is asking about, though.

Comment: @Patrick "*Is there any automatic way*" - I'm trying to show that it's unlikely there is... the format styles can be mixed... So while I guess you could tokenize a bunch of code, and parse strings that ever have `%` applied to them that wouldn't be that simple either... But if the OP just has an isolated list of strings that definitely need converting, then indeed they can get most of the way there with a regex and hand tweak after... or a quick bit of pyparsing...

Comment: @Hooked: You'll have to dig into the details to see the exact differences, since both the PEP and the docs just say they're "similar in concept" or "mostly a superset" etc. without ever listing the exact differences. But I'll edit the answer to show a few off the top of my head.

Comment: Thank you for the nice list of "incompatibilities and complications". Although you mention that it is not complete, it is a good start … and important! I wanted to point out, regarding you mentioning "But why bother?", that it is not sane IMHO to have two coexisting formatting machines in the same language. It may take a while, but `%` _should_ become obsolete, if not with python4, then in python5. It makes it more difficult and cumbersome to learn and handle (for newbies and experts, whatever they say) a language with two interfaces for the same function.

Answer (score 1):

The [docs](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/string.html#formatspec) explain some of the differences. As far as I can tell -- although I'm not very familiar with old-style format strings -- is that the functionality of the new style is a superset of the functionality of the oldstyle.

You'd have to do more tweaking to handle edge cases, but I think something simple like

```
re.replace(r'%(\w+)([sbcdoXnf...])', r'{\1\2}', your_string)
```

would get you 90% of the way there. The remaining translation -- going from things like `%x` to `{0:x}` -- will be too complex for a regular expression to handle (without writing some ridiculously complex conditionals inside of your regex).