# Automatically convert old string formatting style into f-strings

Tags: python-3.x, converters, string-formatting

How could I convert Python's old-style formatting strings, like this:

```
print("You: %s points. Me: %s points." % (score, total - score))
```

into the following?

```
print(f"You: {score} points. Me: {total - score} points.")
```

In fact, for the case of two `%s`, I have written this regular expression:

- search: `"(.*)%s(.*)%s(.*)" % \(([^,\)]+), ([^,\)]+)\)`
- replace: `f"$1{$4}$2{$5}$3"`

One could easily write several other regexes for handling the 1, 3, 4, ... `%s`'s cases, but I am looking for a more general and error-prone approach.

Note: AFAIK, a similar question was asked here in 2013 ([Automatic conversion of the advanced string formatter from the old style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20848493/automatic-conversion-of-the-advanced-string-formatter-from-the-old-style)), when the *f-strings* were not a thing (they were [introduced in Python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals)).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`flynt`](https://github.com/ikamensh/flynt). You call it with the name of a directory and it recursively searches for all .py files and converts `%` formatting to f-strings.

```
flynt <directory_to_process>
```

It will convert `.format()` calls as well as `%` formatting.

You can install it with

```
pip install flynt
```

Be warned that converting `%` to f-strings is not perfect and will produce a different result if you were passing a single element tuple into them (which is why Python moved away from `%` formatting).

Answer (score 4):

Use [`pyupgrade`](https://github.com/asottile/pyupgrade). Specifically, to enable converting to f-strings, use

```
pyupgrade --py36-plus <filename>
```

You can install it with

```
pip install pyupgrade
```

Comment: Following those steps I got `print("You: {} points. Me: {} points.".format(score, total - score))` which doesn't use f-strings.

Comment: @RyanJMcCall from [the readme](https://github.com/asottile/pyupgrade#f-strings) "*note*: `pyupgrade` is intentionally timid and will not create an f-string if it would make the expression longer or if the substitution parameters are anything but simple names or dotted names (as this can decrease readability)."

Comment: so it doesn't answer the question as posed

Comment: @RyanJMcCall check out my new answer https://github.com/ikamensh/flynt